# KeyError while printing trace in pymc3

Tags: python, keyerror, pymc3, mcmc, dirichlet

I'm trying to perform the spectral unmixing technique with the MCMC algorithm. But I encountered a problem while I ran it. This is the part of the code I'm running:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt
import arviz as az

 """
    Perform the spectral unmixing through a MCMC algorithm
    """
    ### SHOW AVAILABLE END MEMBERS
    for l in range(len(TOT_names)):
        print('Index: '+str(l)+',  Compound: '+str(TOT_names[l]))
        
    ### ENDMEMBERS 
    my_arr = []
    lst = list(map(int, input("Which end-members (enter comma separated values): ").split(",")))
    for k in lst:
        my_arr.append(EM[k][i:j])
    ENDM = pm.floatX(np.array(my_arr)) 
    print('ENDMEMBERS ARRAY: ', ENDM.shape)
    
    ### DATA MATRIX
    MATRIX = JM0340_matrix


### DEFINE MCMC MODEL
    with pm.Model() as model:
        # Prior distributions for the abundances
        ABUNDANCES = pm.Dirichlet('abundances', a=np.ones(len(lst)))
        #print('ABUNDANCES ARRAY: ', ABUNDANCES)

        # Constraint on non-negativity of abundances
        pm.Potential('AB_POS_CONSTRAINT', pm.math.switch(pm.math.sum(pm.math.maximum(ABUNDANCES, 0)) - pm.math.sum(ABUNDANCES) < 0, -np.inf, 0))

        # Constraint on the sum of abundances
        AB_SUM = pm.Deterministic('ab_sum', pm.math.sum(ABUNDANCES))
        pm.Potential('AB_SUM_CONSTRAINT', pm.math.switch(tt.abs_(AB_SUM - 1) > 1e-3, -np.inf, 0))

        # Compute modeled spectra
        MODELED_SPECTRA = pm.Deterministic('modeled_spectra', pm.math.dot(ABUNDANCES, ENDM))

        # Likelihood distribution for the data
        DATA = pm.Normal('data', mu=MODELED_SPECTRA, sd=1, observed=MATRIX) #sd standard deviation

        # Sampling Define MCMC model
        TRACE = pm.sample(draws=400, tune=210, chains=8, cores=8, step=pm.Metropolis(), return_inferencedata=True)

        # Extract the trace of the abundances
        ABUND = TRACE['abundances'].mean(axis=0) 
        print('ABUNDANCES ARRAY: ', ABUND.shape)
```

And I got this error:

```
     81 # Extract the trace of the abundances
---> 82 ABUND = TRACE['abundances'].mean(axis=0)  
     83 print('ABUNDANCES ARRAY: ', ABUND.shape)


File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arviz\data\inference_data.py:236, in InferenceData.__getitem__(self, key)
    234 """Get item by key."""
    235 if key not in self._groups_all:
--> 236     raise KeyError(key)
    237 return getattr(self, key)

KeyError: 'abundances'
```

I tried with NUTS and with Metropolis and it is the same. I got the same error.
I'm not able to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Hello @Alex, can you please print the variable `TRACE` and expose it on your question?, seems to me that the dictionary object do not have the key `abundances` and that it is the reason about you are getting the error.

Comment: @FrancoGil thank you. Printing the variable TRACE I've got:
                       `mean     sd  hdi_3%  hdi_97%  mcse_mean  mcse_sd  \
abundances[0]         0.497  0.194   0.136    0.831      0.022    0.016  \ 
abundances[1]         0.026  0.020   0.001    0.061      0.001    0.001   \
abundances[2]         0.286  0.205   0.000    0.631      0.025    0.018   \
abundances[3]         0.192  0.126   0.001    0.415      0.007    0.005   \
ab_sum                1.000  0.000   1.000    1.000      0.000    0.000   \
modeled_spectra[187]  0.059  0.019   0.027    0.095      0.001    0.001 `

Comment: and:
                      `ess_bulk  ess_tail  r_hat  
abundances[0]             80.0     119.0   1.07  /
abundances[1]            150.0     183.0   1.04  /
abundances[2]             64.0      53.0   1.09  /
abundances[3]            277.0     238.0   1.01  /
ab_sum                  3200.0    3200.0    NaN  /
...                        ...       ...    ...  /
modeled_spectra[185]     240.0     493.0   1.03  /
modeled_spectra[186]     242.0     493.0   1.03  /
modeled_spectra[187]     243.0     495.0   1.03  /
[193 rows x 9 columns]`

Comment: @FrancoGil 's comment put me on the right track. The variable `abundances` exists in the output but there are many variables under `abundances` key, so it is necessary to specify which one of these variables I want. So, I wrote: `import arviz as az` `ABUND = az.summary(TRACE, var_names=['abundances'])['mean']` , instead of `ABUND = TRACE['abundances'].mean(axis=0)`